# Swift UIImage Named is nil inside UITableViewController

Tags: swift, xcode, image, null, uiimage

I'm trying to add additional images into my UITableViewController and I have created a function that reads from a bundle which contains all of the images needed to render. The problem is that some images are working as UIImage while others are returning nil when creating UIImage Objects. I'm not sure what is the reason causing this issue because the image is located inside the bundle and previewing it works. Thanks!

```
 //Retrieve Icons
 //Read from file path and append it to an array.


 //Retrieve Icons
    //Read from file path and append it to an array.
    private func loadIcons() {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let bundleURL = Bundle.main.bundleURL
        let assetURL = bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("UIAssets.bundle")
        let contents = try! fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: assetURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: [URLResourceKey.nameKey, URLResourceKey.isDirectoryKey], options: .skipsHiddenFiles)

        //BUG: doesnt work with some png/jpg image is returning nil
        for item in contents {
            let itemStr = item.absoluteString
            if itemStr.contains("png") || itemStr.contains("jpg"){
                let imageName = (itemStr as NSString).lastPathComponent
                print(imageName)
                let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
                self.models[imageName] = image
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: print this line
let itemStr = item.absoluteString

Comment: Use URL not string.

Comment: Also if you have the URL of the image file you don’t need its name. The whole conversion is pointless and unnecessary. Just load the data directly. That is much faster too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm surprised that this is working for *any* images, because `UIImage(named:)` does not work for images inside a subdirectory of your main bundle. It only looks at the top level of the main bundle.

However, the solution is simple: don't use `UIImage(named:)`. Don't use pathnames either. There's absolutely no need for that. You had the solution in your hand: `contentsOfDirectory(at:)` returns an array of URLs, so when you say `for item in contents`, every single `item` *is* the URL of one of your images. So you can just load an `item` directly. Call `Data(contentsOf:item)` to fetch the file data, and turn that into an image with `UIImage(data:)`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification! This helped fixed the issues I had!